# Coluna de Fatores para Date

Tags: r

Meu data frame

```
    x=structure(list(V1 = structure(c(33L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 4L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 1L, 17L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 38L, 40L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 15L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 26L), .Label = c("1-Feb-71", "10-Feb-71", 
"11-Feb-71", "11-Jan-71", "12-Feb-71", "12-Jan-71", "13-Jan-71", 
"14-Jan-71", "15-Feb-71", "15-Jan-71", "16-Feb-71", "17-Feb-71", 
"18-Feb-71", "18-Jan-71", "19-Feb-71", "19-Jan-71", "2-Feb-71", 
"20-Jan-71", "21-Jan-71", "22-Feb-71", "22-Jan-71", "23-Feb-71", 
"24-Feb-71", "25-Feb-71", "25-Jan-71", "26-Feb-71", "26-Jan-71", 
"27-Jan-71", "28-Jan-71", "29-Jan-71", "3-Feb-71", "4-Feb-71", 
"4-Jan-71", "5-Feb-71", "5-Jan-71", "6-Jan-71", "7-Jan-71", "8-Feb-71", 
"8-Jan-71", "9-Feb-71"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 
15L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 7L, 12L, 8L, 16L, 16L, 22L, 16L, 
19L, 22L, 12L, 17L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 21L, 17L, 19L, 16L, 6L, 11L, 
9L, 25L, 25L, 8L, 5L, 13L, 20L, 18L, 16L, 13L, 12L, 14L), .Label = c("7.1359", 
"7.1367", "7.1382", "7.1386", "7.1390", "7.1397", "7.1403", "7.1406", 
"7.1410", "7.1411", "7.1412", "7.1414", "7.1418", "7.1420", "7.1422", 
"7.1429", "7.1431", "7.1434", "7.1435", "7.1437", "7.1439", "7.1443", 
"7.1445", "7.1465", "ND"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -40L))
```

Como faço para converter a coluna V1 para data?

Eu faço isso:

`x$V1 <- as.Date(x$V1, format="%d-%m-%Y")` , mas sai `<NA>`.

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria assim:

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(as.character(x$V1))
```

Note que como a coluna V1 está carregada como `factor` no R, precisei converter em caractere primeiro, o ideal seria você ter lido a sua base com o argumento `stringAsFactors = FALSE`, ou usar as funções do `readr` que fazem isso por default.

O `lubridate` possui diversas funções para converter texto em data: `dmy` indica que as datas estão no formato dia-mês-ano, mas tem função p/ todas as permutações `ymd`, `mdy`, etc. Também tem função para quando as datas são acompanhadas do horário: `dmy_hms`, por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

O formato da data não está correto. Use

```
x$V1 <- as.Date(x$V1, format="%d-%b-%y")
```

Mais informações sobre formato de data podem ser encontradas utilizando `?strptime`.

Comment: Obrigado, Marcus, mas continua a aparecer NA´s. A minha serie historica é maior. Editei la na pergunta.

Comment: É um arquivo txt bem grande. Varias datas são corrigidas e outras continua aparecendo NA´s.

Comment: O código que passei resolve o problema colocado na pergunta, para o data frame informado. Eu não tenho como avaliar o problema de aparecimento de NA em alguma outra posição do vetor se não tenho acesso a esta posição.